# Filtering out DataRows that don't have Parents

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, foreign-keys, dataset, parent-child

I have a two tables in a DataSet that have a Parent-Child relation. The Parent is built from external data that I don't have control over, while the Child is sourced from the database that I am using for my internal data. This means that I can't always be certain that there will be a Parent for my Children. If this happens, I would prefer to filter out the Children from the DataGridView that is consuming the data via a BindingSource; I don't want to remove the rows from the database because settings changes (or other events I have no control over) might reintroduce rows that were previously present and removed.

I had previously had to figure out how to go the opposite way, to create Children for previously unencountered Parents via:

```
 dim newrows() as ParentRow = ParentTable.Select("Count(Child(MyRelation).ForeignKeyColumn) < 1")
 For Each row as ParentRow in newrows
      ChildRow.AddChildRow(row, otherData)
 Next
```

I thought I could use a similar approach:

```
 BindingSource.Filter = "PARENT(MyRelation).KeyColumn IS NOT NULL"
```

But this filters out everything. Investigating, I discovered that running

```
 ChildTable.Select("PARENT(MyRelation).KeyColumn IS NULL")(0).GetParentRow("MyRelation").Item("KeyColumn")
```

on a table where the given result has a parent succeeds and gives a value, which seems to contradict the Select statement, so clearly something unexpected is happening with the Select statement.

I am at a loss. Is there any way to filter out (but retain in the backend) rows that don't have a parent via the BindingSource? What am I not seeing here?

Comment: Surely it's just along the lines of `childBindingSource.Filter = "ForeignKeyColumn IS NOT NULL"`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Except the ForeignKeyColumn won't be Null. It will have a value referencing a foreign column that is not available at the moment, for whatever reason. If it were Null, that would violate the need to be able to reconnect to it if it does come back in scope later.

Comment: Ah, I see. So the child record does have a parent in the database but not in the `DataSet`. I guess you could generate a list of existing parent IDs and use an `IN` clause in the filter but that's not very dynamic.

Comment: Okay, it turns out that my Filter does work if I turn constraints back on. However, this (obviously) throws an error if the Parent doesn't exist in the DataSet, leaving me in a similar position.

Comment: Can you add a Boolean column in the child table that indicates if the parent record exists, and do a loop to fill in yes/no, then filter on that?

Comment: @SSS I think that does sound better than any idea I've had so far.

Comment: @SSS Well, that was embarrassingly easy: it works now. If you want to write that up as an answer and nobody answers with a more direct way to do this in the next couple days, I'd be happy to accept it as the answer.

Comment: Oops, I spoke too soon. Now the rows are being marked as changed, which could interfere with tracking changes for the purposes of saving. I might be able to immediately AcceptChanges on initial load to dodge it, but I'm going to have to inspect whether or not it will cause problems outside of initial load.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

It turns out that making a Boolean column with an expression that calculates `Parent.Key IS NOT NULL` works and is filterable by the BindingSource, without throwing a flag for the row having been changed.

### Possible Explanation

Combined with the observation that the original method only fails when constraints are turned off, this makes me think that this might be a design decision by Microsoft in light of the fact that, when constraints are off, there is no guarantee that a Child will only have one Parent. So the filtering by a Parent column will fail when the constraints are off, but filtering by a column calculated by the Parent column doesn't care about the constraints and so is okay. I just have to do my own work to make sure that there is only one Parent; fortunately this is guaranteed by the data source I am generating the Parent from.